# Forcing div to overflow?

Tags: html, css, overflow

My div size is the black border, and I want my icons to spill over into the grey area on the right, so the twitter icon is at the center. They should all be on the same line.

I'm currently using this:

```
 <div class="social-icon-medium" style="max-width: 500%; padding-left: 50% !important; display: inline-block !important;">
```

Thank you!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF4Az.png)

Comment: Please add relevant code to the question, so that we can duplicate the problem

Answer (score 0):

Alicia.
I bet, that you want to do something like this

```css
.container {
    height: 200px;
    background: light-grey;
}
.white-area {
    background: white;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 70px;
}

.icons-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    right: -100%;
}

img {
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="white-area">
      <div class="icons-wrapper">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/174/174848.svg" alt="Facebook free icon" title="Facebook free icon">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/174/174876.svg" alt="Twitter free icon" title="Twitter free icon">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/174/174883.png" alt="Youtube free icon" "="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I suggest u to read more about overflow and positioning in CSS.
I would recommend W3Schools for beginning.

- Overflow explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)
- Positioning of elements [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Will try this.